# How to include the sqlite3 library "libsqlite3.0.dylib" in my application source file?

Tags: macos, open-source, include

I am writing an application in C++/C/Object-C cocoa environment for OSX 10.6

For specific reasons, I cannot make changes to the make file so that I can not link the "libsqlite3.0.dylib" library during build.

In my source files, I included . Since I cannot link the library with the framework, I was wondering how can include a library as part my source file, specifically how do I include libsqlite3.0.dylib?

usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib

this is for MAX OSX 10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot include an already-compiled library into your source code and use it. You absolutely need source code statements in source code.

However, you can include the [sources of sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.17.tar.gz) in your source code. In this tar file, the sqlite source code is in sqlite3.c.

Comment: Interesting, I just need to include sqlite3.c in my source file would that still work since I can't change the make file of the project?

Comment: Yes, if you include the C file in some other C file, you don't need to change the Makefile. You may have to include some of the header files as well.

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't work during compile time be the sqlite3 functions are not referenced. 

I am working around this issue by creating a temporarily local makefile that will include the sqlite3 library